# Using Variable Explorer in Spyder (Python) to View Other Namespaces

Tags: python, debugging, namespaces, scientific-computing, spyder

Is it possible to view namespaces other than `Global` in the Spyder variable explorer?  I'd like to clean up my code to get things into main(), but I still need to take a look at variable contents at this stage in development.

EDIT:  Assume my script currently only contains:

```
a = 2
b = 4
c = a + b
```

I run this in Spyder, I can use the variable explorer post-run to view `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Now if I wrap this in main(), per less-bad coding practice:

```
def main():
   a = 2
   b = 4
   c = a + b
```

Now I can no longer view them post-run in the variable explorer.  (The comment suggests a breakpoint, but this is being used to interface to an instrument in real-time, so I can't pause execution).  /end EDIT.

Are my only choices to either (1) leave the code with variables I need to look at outside of a function or (2) export the variables I'll want to examine into the global namespace from main()?  Either solution leaves me with something to do/undo later.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) I'm not sure if I follow you but you could set a breakpoint, then enter in debug mode and inspect your *local* variables (which our variable explorer is able to show) by stepping line by line in your program.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify; in particular, the program is being used to interface to / log from a piece of test equipment, so I can't pause execution.  Not really important to my question, but the main motivation is that I have the script running as a command-line application now; I'd like to be able to move it into the GUI shell I created so I can plot, but that will mean the variables that used to be in the local namespace will all now be in some function's namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible at the moment with Spyder. This is the closest thing you can do to get the result you want:

```
import inspect

local_vars = {}

def main():
    global local_vars
    a = 2
    b = 4
    c = a+b
    local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_locals
    return c

main()
```

After running it you should see that the `local_vars` dictionary contains the local variables defined inside the `main` function.

*Note*: After giving double-click to `local_vars` contents, Spyder will open a new window which is basically equivalent to the view shown in our variable explorer but only with your local variables.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick help, particularly the line on exporting everything at once as a dictionary - haven't seen that trick before.  And thanks for the work on Spyder, BTW, which is displacing MATLAB in my workflow.

Comment: Glad you liked it :) This is one of the things why I really love Python: its terrific introspection capabilities.